# Where does `resolvconf` gets the IPs of DNS servers from?

Tags: networking, server, dns, resolv.conf, resolvconf

On a server machine, I have the `/etc/network/interfaces` file similar to:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.35
    netmask 255.255.252.0 
    network 192.168.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.3.255
    gateway 192.168.1.1 
    dns-nameservers 192.168.1.3 192.168.1.4
    dns-search example.com
```

When running `resolvconf -u`, the `/etc/resolv.conf` file becomes:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 192.168.1.3
nameserver 192.168.1.4
search pelicandd.com
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 192.168.1.13
```

Why is there a `nameserver 192.168.1.13`?

Comment: Do you have any entries in `/etc/resolvconf/resolvconf.d/base` or `/etc/resolvconf/resolvconf.d/head`?

Comment: @muru: `base` is an empty file and `head` contains the "[...] DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE [...]". But there is a `tail` symbolic link which points to `original` which indeed contains the problematic IP. Can you promote your helpful comment to an answer, please?

Comment: Done, but we still don't know what added this entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvconf generates `/etc/resolv.conf` using files in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/` in the order: `head`, `base`, `tail`.  The `head` file is almost always present and contains just the warning message about generated files. The `base` file may also be present, but is empty by default. There might be a `tail` file, and this is likely the culprit in your case given that the rogue entry appears at the end.